# Set multiple typed variables to null

Tags: scala

I have a bunch of lazy val Strings that I'd like to set all at once, and there is a certain case where they should be set to `null` (I know this is not the Scala way, but it is for Java compatibility)

Normally I can set the variables in the typical multi-assignment manner:

```
scala> val (a: String, b: String) = ("a", "b")
a: String = a
b: String = b
```

As soon as I add a null into the mix, everything goes haywire:

```
scala> val (a: String, b: String) = (null, null)
<console>:12: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : String
 required: Null
       val (a: String, b: String) = (null, null)
               ^
<console>:12: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : String
 required: Null
       val (a: String, b: String) = (null, null)
```

Is there a way to set multiple typed variables to null?

I'm guessing this has something to do with the pattern matching involved in setting multiple variables since this is just fine:

```
scala> val a: String = null
a: String = null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax seems to work.

```
scala> val (a, b) = (null, null): Tuple2[String,String]
a: String = null
b: String = null
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a puzzler for the pattern match:

http://scalapuzzlers.com/#pzzlr-035

Did no one offer the obvious?

```
scala> val a,b,c: String = null
a: String = null
b: String = null
c: String = null
```

AIA if I'm missing something.

The difference is specified in 4.1.

Comment: I Picked Tim's answer because it allows you to set some values to null and others to non-null values.

Answer (score 2):

Working alternatives

```
scala> val (a,b): (String,String) = (null, null)
a: String = null
b: String = null

scala> val (a, b) = (null: String, null: String)
a: String = null
b: String = null

scala> val (a,b) = (null, null): (String, String)
a: String = null
b: String = null
```

Answer (score 2):

To be more concise you can use this syntax:

```
scala> val a,b = null:String
a: String = null
b: String = null
```

Comment: Or `val d,e,f = null.asInstanceOf[String]`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in you example is in `val (a: String, b: String)`. You try to specify types of varibles, but this kind of syntax is shortcut for tuple.

If you want to directly specify type you can use this kind of syntax:

```
scala> val (x, y): Tuple2[String, String] = (null, null)
x: String = null
y: String = null
```